# Reasoning about $2^m - 3^n$ where $m>0,n>0$ are integers

Tags: summation, solution-verification, exponentiation

Let:

- $m>0, n>0, c>0$ be integers

Does it follow that:

$$2^m - 3^n = \begin{cases}
-3^n(1 - 2^{-c}) + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i-c}\right), & m=2n-c\\
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i}\right), & m=2n\\
3^n(2^c - 1) + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i+c}\right), & m=2n+c\\
\end{cases}$$

Is there a more standard way to state these relations?  Did I make any mistakes?

Here is my reasoning:

- **Case 1**:  $m=2n$

$$2^{2n} - 3^n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i}\right)$$

- **Base Case:** For $n=2:$

> $$2^4 - 3^2 = 3 + 2^2$$

- **Inductive Hypothesis**:

> $$\text{Assume that up to }n \ge 2 \text{ that }2^{2n} - 3^n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i}\right)$$

- **Inductive Case**:

> - $2^{2n+2} - 3^{n+1} = 4^{n+1} - 3^{n+1} = 3(4^n - 3^n) +2^{2n} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(3^{n-i}2^{2i}\right) + 2^{2n} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left(3^{n-i}2^{2i}\right)$

- **Case 2**:  $m < 2n$ with $m = 2n - c$

$$2^{2n-c} - 3^n = -3^n(1 - 2^{-c}) + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i-c}\right)$$

- **Base Case:** For $c=1:$

> - $2^{2n-1} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[3^n + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i}\right)\right] = 3^{n}2^{-1} + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i-1}\right)$
> - $2^{2n-1} - 3^n = -3^{n}2^{-1} + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i-1}\right)$

- **Inductive Hypothesis**:

> $$\text{Assume that up to }c \ge 1 \text{ that }2^{2n-c} - 3^n = -3^n(1 - 2^{-c}) + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i-c}\right)$$

- **Inductive Case**:

> - $2^{2n-(c+1)} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[3^n + -3^n(1 - 2^{-c}) + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i-c}\right)\right] = 3^n2^{-(c+1)} + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i-(c+1)}\right)$
> - $2^{2n-(c+1)} - 3^{n} =-3^n(1 - 2^{-(c+1)}) +  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i-(c+1)}\right)$

- **Case 3**:  $m > 2n$ with $m = 2n + c$

$$2^{2n+c} - 3^n = $3^n(2^c - 1) + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i+c}\right)$$

- **Base Case:** For $c=1:$

> - $2^{2n+1} = 2\left[3^n + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i}\right)\right] = 3^{n}2 + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i+1}\right)$
> - $2^{2n-1} - 3^n = 3^n + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i+1}\right)$

- **Inductive Hypothesis**:

> $$\text{Assume that up to }c \ge 1 \text{ that }2^{2n+c} - 3^n = 3^n(2^c - 1) + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i+c}\right)$$

- **Inductive Case**:

> - $2^{2n+(c+1)} = 2\left[3^n + 3^n(2^c-1) + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i+c}\right)\right] = 3^n2^{c+1} + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i+(c+1)}\right)$
> - $2^{2n+(c+1)} - 3^{n} =3^n(2^{c+1}-1) +  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i-(c+1)}\right)$

Comment: What you've done looks correct to me. I think that you can write it as $$2^{2n+d}-3^n=3^n(2^d - 1) + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i+d}\right)$$ where $d$ is an **integer**.

Comment: Thanks!  That's a nice generalization of the $3$ cases!

Comment: @integrand Thanks for the comment.  I have updated the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done also looks correct to me. As [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/78967/mathlove)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837024/reasoning-about-2m-3n-where-m0-n0-are-integers#comment7914060_3837024) states, you can combine your $3$ cases into $1$ equation by using $m = 2n + d$, with $d$ being an integer (i.e., $-c$, $0$ or $c$ in your $3$ cases), to get

$$2^{2n + d} - 3^{n} = 3^{n}(2^{d} - 1) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(3^{n-1-i}2^{2i+d}) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

To prove \eqref{eq1A}, although induction works as you've done, I believe it's simpler & easier to use that for any real $x$ and $y$, and positive integer $n$, we have

$$x^n - y^{n} = (x - y)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-i}y^{i}\right) = (x - y)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}y^{n-1-i}x^{i}\right) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

In your case, $x = 2^2$ and $y = 3$, giving

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2^{2n} - 3^{n} & = (2^2 - 3)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}3^{n-1-i}(2^2)^{i}\right) \\
2^{d}\left(2^{2n} - 3^{n}\right) & = 2^{d}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}3^{n-1-i}2^{2i}\right) \\
2^{d}\left(2^{2n} - 3^{n}\right) & = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}3^{n-1-i}2^{2i + d} \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Using this in place of the summation in \eqref{eq1A} means its right side becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
3^{n}(2^{d} - 1) + 2^{d}\left(2^{2n} - 3^{n}\right) & = 3^{n}2^{d} - 3^{n} + 2^{2n+d} - 3^{n}2^{d} \\
& = 2^{2n+d} - 3^{n}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Since this equals the left side of \eqref{eq1A}, it confirms that equation is always true.